# Assigning data from closure after dataTaskWithURL resulting in nil values

Tags: rest, swift2, ios9, xcode7, nsurlsession

I apologize for the simplicity of my description, I'm new to Swift as a language.

I have a REST api which provides all the data to my app.  I am attempting to populate a table view from a JSON feed.  Essentially, I am trying to my best to stick to the MVC patterns I use in web development.  So I've built a model of my data object, and then a list model to contain individual instances of that object.

The actual problem however is, when I initiate the whole process (last code sample) the result count is 0 however that's simply because the data response for the API call hasn't happened yet.  I'd rather not use synchronous calls, but I'm feeling like that's the only way I'm going to fix this, unless I start mucking my API calls directly into the controller itself?

```
class NewsItem {
    var id: Int
    var headline: String
    var summary: String
    var created: String
    var source: String
    var company: String
    var companyLogo: UIImage

    init(headline: String, summary: String, created: String, source: String, company: String, companyLogoUrl: String, id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.headline = headline
        self.summary = summary
        self.created = created
        self.source = source
        self.company = company

        if let url = NSURL(string: companyLogoUrl) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                companyLogo = UIImage(data: data)!
            } else {
                companyLogo = UIImage(named: "DefaultLogo")!
            }
        } else {
            companyLogo = UIImage(named: "DefaultLogo")!
        }
    }
}
```

I then have my NewsList class which actually builds an array of news items using a closure for the rest call.

```
class NewsList {
    var name: String
    var newsItems: [NewsItem]

    init(named: String, includeNewsItems: [NewsItem]) {
        name = named
        newsItems = includeNewsItems
    }

    class func getNewsItems() -> [NewsList] {
        return [self.parsedNews()]
    }

    private class func parsedNews() -> NewsList {
        var newsItems = [NewsItem]()

        api.getLatestActivityData({JSONData, error -> Void in
            if (JSONData != nil) {
                for (_, subJSON) in JSONData["data"] {
                    let headline  = subJSON["headline"].string!
                    let summary = subJSON["summary"].string!
                    let created = subJSON["created"].string!
                    let source = subJSON["source"].string!
                    let company = subJSON["company"].string!
                    let companyLogo = subJSON["companyLogo"].string!
                    let id = subJSON["id"].int!

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        newsItems.append(NewsItem(headline: headline, summary: summary, created: created, source: source, company: company, companyLogoUrl: companyLogo, id: id))
                    })
                }
            } else {
                print("api data fetch failed")
                print(error)
            }
        })

        return NewsList(named: "News", includeNewsItems: newsItems)
    }
}
```

For the call above, I've got the following method inside my a RemoteAPI class

```
func getLatestActivityData(completionHandler: ((JSON!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void {
        let requestUrl = self.baseUrl + "xxxxxxx"
        print("Request URL: " + requestUrl)

        let url = NSURL(string: requestUrl)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.setValue("text/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                return completionHandler(nil, error)
            }

            print("Latest activity response received")
            let returnString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let jsonData = returnString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)

            if (error != nil) {
                return completionHandler(nil, error)
            } else {
                return completionHandler(readableJSON, nil)
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

To actually initiate the entire above convoluted process, I have this in my view controller

```
var newsItems: [NewsItem] {
    var newsList = NewsList.getNewsItems()
    return newsList[0].newsItems
}
```

Here is our pain point.  If I fire `print(newsItems.count)` after the above call, the result is 0.  However a second or two later, the callback handler will actually receive the data and begin assigning items to the `newsList` array.

How do I prevent the array assignment until the data is actually received?   Am I just going about this entirely the wrong way?

XCODE 7 + Swift 2.0 + iOS 9.0.x

Comment: So, upon further reading I think where I'm going wrong here is I should be updating the tableview inside the closure, instead of simply assigning the data to an array in the main thread and then returning that array.

I will try toying with this and answer my own question for informational purposes if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was in how I was using the closure.  I was depending upon my closure to assign values outside the closure and then the completion handler to return those values.

**Solution:**

1. I removed the entire NewsList class, its actually redundant to what I am doing
2. I changed the call in my view controller to do the following

   ```
   var newsItems = [NewsItem]()

   api.getLatestActivityData({JSONData, error -> Void in
       if (JSONData != nil) {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               for (_, subJSON) in JSONData["data"] {
                   let headline  = subJSON["headline"].string!
                   let summary = subJSON["summary"].string!
                   let created = subJSON["created"].string!
                   let source = subJSON["source"].string!
                   let company = subJSON["company"].string!
                   let companyLogo = subJSON["companyLogo"].string!
                   let id = subJSON["id"].int!

                   newsItems.append(NewsItem(headline: headline, summary: summary, created: created, source: source, company: company, companyLogoUrl: companyLogo, id: id))
               }

               self.activityTableView.reloadData()
           })
       } else {
           print("api data fetch failed")
           print(error)
       }
   })
   ```

Now all I should need to do is once the for loop is done, I should be able to update the table with a reload.

For the 'newer' swift users like me, something I didn't understand which would have helped to know yesterday ... When you call `tableView.reloadData()` the app will trigger all the tabieView related events, if your data source has been updated from the closure as mine is above, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` will be able to correctly update.  Just assign your data in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Hope this helps someone!